# What type of wire do I need for garage door sensors?

Tags: wiring, garage-door

My garage door is failing to close.  The light blinks 10 times and the internal indicator light blinks twice.  Also, the sensors seem to be working properly.  From my research, this indicates there is a short/fault in the sensor wiring.  The wiring to the sensors is done rather shoddily.  The wires have multiple splices, some held together with electrical tape, some splices are exposed and just twisted together.  In addition to that, its hung in a half-ass way.  So I thought I would remove the old wiring and put it new wiring.  However, I do not know what type of wire to purchase.

What should I be getting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically 22/2 bell wire is used.  You can pick it up at any hardware store.

Comment: It's just a simple two-lobe solid wire, like a miniature lamp cord. It's often white with a red stripe on one lobe to help you maintain polarity in your circuit. Actually, you probably have it coming out of your sensors now.

Comment: Amazingly the garage door worked when I got home from home depot.  But this isnt the first time this has happened.  I have the wire, so no reason not to use it.